# How to avoid resetting global variables in a js file

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to use localStorage for global variables in a small site (less than 10 pages). I'd like to declare the variables in a js file, but keep them from resetting on every page load.

Is there a way to prevent a few lines from reloading other than just blocking/resetting with yet another global?

```
/** placed in a sj file **/
if(localStorage['lock'] != '1') {
  localStorage['val1'] = '0';
  localStorage['val2'] = '0';
  localStorage['val3'] = '0';

  localStorage['lock'] = '1';
}
```

Comment: `localStorage` is a permanent cookie which doesn't rest on a page reload, or even when the session ends.

Comment: Having an entry in `localStorage` which tells you whether it was initialized or not seems to be a reasonable solution. However, you can use an existing entry for that, e.g. `if (localStorage.getItem('val1') != null)`

Comment: You might not need another property (and could use `localStorage.length` or so), but in general this is how it works, yes. It might be more convenient to do an existence check on each single property, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Local_Storage) does not have any locking hability.

The solution you found is neat and fine by me. It has the advantage to be fast (because it only checks one key).

However, you may want to add a small level of abstraction on the top of what you've already done. But that's essentially a matter of taste (the performance impact is small here).

```
function freezeInLocalStorage(key, value) {
  if (typeof localStorage[key] !== 'string') {
    localStorage[key] = value;
  }
}

freezeInLocalStorage('val1', '0');
freezeInLocalStorage('val2', '0');
freezeInLocalStorage('val3', '0');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/s4oamvbm/1/)

Comment: This won't work if empty strings are possible values for the entries (empty strings are falsy).

Comment: this method can still work, you just need to account for all possible valid entries.

Comment: @JosephNeathawk: we only have to check for the string type as the localStorage implicitly casts when storing new values.

Comment: What I was getting at was that if en empty string wasn't going to be a valid entry in the first place then it didn't need to be accounted for. Your update takes care of empty strings, but it may be the case that empty strings SHOULD be overwritten with valid data, in this case your original code would have been a better choice. Perhaps put both options in your answer...?

Comment: I got your point. Needless to say it needs to be tweaked depending on individual needs. This version sticks better with the OP's question as it declares a key once only.